# Bind to another controls behavior

Tags: wpf, xaml, behavior

I've created a blend behavior to set the columns of a data grid.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:DataGridBehavior ColumnsSource="{Binding SourceHeaders}"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</DataGrid>
```

What I'd like to be able to do now, is consume that ColumnsSource in another control (this is currently being capture in Template property of style).  Something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={{Binding ???, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}} />
```

Based on the lack of search results, I am not sure if this is possible.
I am starting down the research of Attached Properties, but is what I wanted to do is possible?

Comment: What does the behaviour do, i.e. what property does it set? Bind to this one.

Comment: @mm8 the behavior is essentially a custom implementation of "AutoGenerateColumns".  It takes a collection of objects to define the order, name, etc., of the columns.  Once it is consumed but the DataGrid, there is no copy of the collection available, and since I am referencing this table in the style/other control, I don't have access to the original source.  I don't want to get too fixated on this specific use (it was the first handy code snippit), but whether or not I can bind retrieve this behavior's property and bind it to another control.